# I'm confusing between NTLM and NTLM (on network)

Tags: windows, encryption, ntlm

Im doing a little research about Windows password and I've a little question.

Windows encrypt user passwords and store them on: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\SAM` encrypting them by the **NTLM** algorithm (plus Syskey)

**NTLM** is also a network authentication protocols, so I'm messing up with this.

I would like to know if the **NTLM encryption** is the same of the **NTLM network protocol**. I mean, in Windows, when you type your user and password, if the system starts a network protocol on the same system (localhost), as it would if they were too different computers (ip).

Or otherwise, if they are two different things with the same name.
It would be great if someone could give me a little explanation about the difference of both methods.

Hope you can understand my question, as I'm not English!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft, but not on Windows or any team that developed NTLM.  This knowledge comes from external sources and thus may not be accurate.

NTLM is two things:  a one-way hash algorithm and an authentication protocol.

The one-way hash function is what the Windows OS uses to store passwords (in the secrets file, as you note.)  This is, of course, so that plaintext passwords need not be stored on disk.  When you type your password on the login screen, it will be hashed with the NTLM hash algorithm and compared against the existing hash in the secrets file.  If they match, you'll be authenticated.  If not, you'll be prompted to enter your password again.

The authentication protocol is a challenge/response protocol that authenticates some on-the-wire protocol like CIFS or HTTP.  The algorithm utilizes the aforementioned NTLM hash algorithms in order to build the responses to the server's challenges based on the password that the user typed.  The protocol specification for the NTLM authentication protocol is available from Microsoft under their Open Specifications license.

To answer your question, when you log in to Windows, it's likely just using the NTLM hash and checking it against the on-disk file, not doing some network call.  Of course, if your machine happened to be a domain controller (and, somehow, couldn't do Kerberos) then it may do NTLM authentication over the network to localhost, but that's a pretty contrived example.  Of course, if you're hitting a network resource on that local machine (say, CIFS file sharing or hitting a web site) then you'll be using the network authentication protocol, not going directly to the secrets file.

Answer (score 0):

NTLM is not a network protocol. It's an authentication protocol. They are totally separate things.

There's a pretty good discussion of [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) here. Pay special attention to the fact that NTLM isn't used any longer (it's been replaced by Kerberos and NTLM2, both of which are defined and discussed in the linked article).

Comment: I've checked the Wikipedia article some weeks ago. As you can see it starts with "In a Windows network..."

I want to know the differences between NTLM on a network and NTLM encryption when a user types his password on his computer and gets loged in (or not).

Comment: That's explained in the article as well. It talks about NTLM (now NTLM2) being used under circumstances when a domain isn't available, or when the authentication is being done via an IP address. Read the entire article; it answers every question or comment you've made so far. In fact, the comment you made in response to my answer is addressed in the first section (the final paragraph starting with "While Kerberos").

Comment: But the wikipedia article only discusses NTLM as an authentication protocol (over the network), it does not discuss the NTLM hash algorithm used for the SAM file.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to say Edward. I want a comparation between both.

Comment: Yes, my statement was indicated for Ken White.  Borja, please see my answer below.